# Eclipse Auto-Suggest For Variables

Tags: eclipse, autosuggest

So I'm using eclipse, and one thing I've noticed is that after the dot(.), it will provide auto suggest. But not anytime else. So say I'm typing out float x = health;, I would have to type out health. I know that you can do Cntrl+Space, but how do I make it do it automatically.

Comment: In case you are talking about Java, in the preferences _Java > Editor > Content Assist_ you can specify when code completion will be triggered (on which character typed; by default it's only `.`).

Comment: But how would I make it trigger on all characters?

Comment: Instead of `.` use e.g. `._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@$`.

Comment: I did not think of that.

Comment: It worked, tysm.